# numerar automatico escritura registros repetidos MySQL

Tags: mysql

Para pillar una averia muy exporadica de maquina, capturamos eventos con un arduino, y se guardan en el MySQL del portatil.

Lo elegante es usar fecha y hora como indices.

El problema es que suelen venir de golpe muchos por segundo. y nos da error de "duplicate key".

Soluciones:

1º Guardar los duplicados, sin mas, tenia entendido que no se puede, pero antes de preguntar aqui, pregunte a google, y hay un monton de casos de registros repetidos, ¿se puede o no repetir clave?.

2º Meter una 3º columna de tick (fracion de segundo), en principio no. nos llega fecha y hora, no depende de nosotros.

3º Meter una columna con autoincremento, y usarla de indice. feo.

4º Esa columna usarla como 3ª key combinada.

5º la 3º columna en principio vale 0 siempre, si duplicate key -> incrementar -> volver a intentar, hasta que trage.

Como lo metemos en la base datos con C# esto es lo que hago, y funciona, pero es lento. 
Seguramente hay una manera de hacer eso de manera automatica.

de momento esto es como creo la tabla.

```
        public string Txt_Crea_Dia_Aux(string ruta)
    {
        string txtSend = @"
        CREATE TABLE `" + ruta + @"` (
        `fec` int(6) NOT NULL,
        `hor` int(6) NOT NULL,
        `presion` decimal(5, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
        `rpms` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
        `angulo` float DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(`fec`,`hor`)
        );";
        return txtSend;
    }
```

- fecha y hora las paso a int, por no aclararme con los tiempos, y por haber leido que lo mejor para los indices son los int

EDITADO AÑADIDO:

6º Como por medio se procesa con C# , es facil

```
        if(horBak == Reg.hor) { repBak++; }//si coincide hora, campo incremental ++
        else { repBak = 0; horBak = Reg.hor; } //sino, resetea el incremental, y se entera de la nueva hora
        Reg.rep = repBak; //mete el incremental en el registro
```

pero la pregunta era, ¿si existe manera de que lo haga MySQL?,

Comment: No me parece feo poner un campo incremental. De hecho considero que es tu mejor baza. Muchos orm se basan precisamente en esa clave para las operaciones. Otra forma es que guardes un timestamp con microsegundos. Así es muy difícil que te coincidan, ya que solo una operación de insert lleva más de 1 microsegundos. Pero si quieres seguir guardando fecha y hora deberas quitarlos de ser key y añadir ese timestamp

Comment: El error, a mi juicio, es conceptual: no tienes clara la diferencia entre clave duplicada y registro (fila) duplicado. Definiendo eso ya tienes la solución. O sea, ¿debe haber solo un registro por cada fecha/hora? o ¿los registros son únicos por cada **instante** (fecha/hora/minuto/segundo/milisegundo)? Aclarado eso, la PK puede ser una columna `DATETIME` o `TIMESTAMP`. No veo por qué complicarse la vida con un autoincrement en este caso cuando ya hay una columna que por su propia definición podría ser perfectamente llave primaria.